# Cloudkit Web Service Query BadRequestException

Tags: cloudkit, cloudkit-web-services

I'm trying to query CloudKit for a simple object where the name equals a string but I am getting back a `BadRequestException`.

The RecordType is "Teacher" with parameters "Name" and "Grade".

I'm guessing there is something wrong with my query filter but can't find anything out of spec for Apple's reference.

```
    {"query": {
          "filterBy": {
             "fieldName": "Name", "fieldValue": {
               "type": "STRING", "value": {
                "Name": "Teacher 1"
                }
              }, 
              "comparator": "EQUALS"
           }, 
        "recordType": "Teacher"
     }, 
   "zoneID": {"zoneName": "_defaultZone"}
}
```

Resulting Error:

> {u'serverErrorCode': u'BAD_REQUEST', u'reason': u'BadRequestException:
>   Invalid value, expected type STRING but actual value was object of
>   class com.apple.cloudkit.ws.application.common.data.UnknownTypeModel',
>   u'uuid': u'c254448d-130e-4c6c-8170-554d976a1789'}

Comment: It's a little difficult to figure out which one of the above is a variable. Maybe you could expand the code snippet a little. but... Isn't teacher by any chance an object?

Comment: I updated the question with more details and expanded the filter query.

Comment: Can you try something for me and use `systemFieldName` instead of `fieldName`?

Comment: Same Exception but different error. BadRequestException: Unexpected input at [line: 1, column: 137]'

Comment: Check this out: http://www.hamagain.com/2016/09/30/cloudkitjs-error/ - looks like you are accidentally adding an extra "value:{}" to your query.

Comment: Lefty - You were really close, it wasn't the value that was wrong but it was putting the field name in again since I already have "Name" set in the "fieldName" parameter, in fieldValue it needed to be {"value":"Teacher 1"}.  If you add that as an answer i'll accept it.

Comment: Done, I am glad you managed to figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to put the field name in again, as `"Name"` is  already set in the `"fieldName"` parameter. In `fieldValue`, it only needs to be `{"value":"Teacher 1"}`.

(The inspiration to the solution came from [CloudKit JS Sample Code Error](http://hamagain.com/2016/09/30/cloudkitjs-error)).